# DataLayer variables are in GTM Debug but not showing in GA4 DebugView

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-tag-manager

As you can see, this is GTM's debug and this `Action` variable is present here with a value in the Data Layer.

[image: GTM tagassistant]

This is the GA4 event that I created in GTM in which I enabled `Send Ecommerce Data` and also, this `Action` variable is defined as an Event Parameter with Data Layer type (Version 2).

[image: GTM tag is fired]

This is GA4 Debug View and there is no `Action` param here.

[image: But it's not being appeared in ga4 debugview]

Can somebody please tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't map the Action variable to anything?

Seems to me like you may be missing a debugging step or two. Before you go to GA4 real time report, you still have stuff to look at in the inspector.

On your second screenshot, you see which tags fired on your selected event. Clicking on those will show you which variables are supplied with them. You can switch to the values view to see which values are sent in them.

Sometimes the inspector won't show you all variables (unless they fixed it). In that case, you open your network tab, filter by "collect" and inspect the payload in the event to see what's sent.

If you expect the `Send Ecommerce Data` to do the heavy lifting for you, you have to supply it with the EEC events in the syntax it expects in the dataLayer. [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ua/gtm/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases).